# django 1.6 url tag error

Tags: django, django-1.6

I have problem with my app1 application :

```
Reverse for 'app1.views.add_content' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/add-content/(\\d+)/$']
```

views

```
@login_required
def add_content(request, category_id):
    form = ContentForm()
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            content = Content()
            content content_code = form.cleaned_data['content_code']
            content.product_versions = form.cleaned_data['product_versions']
            content.category = category
            content.creator = request.user

            content.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('category-detail', args=(category.id, )))

    return render_to_response('add_content.html', {
            'form': form,
            'category': category,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls

```
url(r'^/add-content/(\d+)/$', 'app1.views.add_content', name='add_content'),
```

in template i have error in this line

```
<a id="add_content" class="button" href="{% url 'app1.views.add_content' pk %}">Add New Content</a>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Looks like `pk` is not defined in your template. I don't see you passing `pk` to the template in `render_to_response`. Perhaps you meant `category.pk` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i missread Add content as add category,

your mistake is here:

```
{% url 'app1.views.add_content' pk %}
```

it should be this:

```
{% url 'app1.views.add_content' category.pk %}
```

Comment: i try add in turn: category.pk , category.id, category_id but have the same error

Comment: In your url you should have: `url(r'^/add-content/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', 'app1.views.add_content', name='add_content'),`

Comment: add your solution in urls and in templates used all of the above but have the same error((

Comment: Reverse for 'app1.views.add_content' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/add-content/(?P<category_id>\\d+)/$']

Comment: You are not passing any argument, are you sure category is defined in your template?

Comment: i try replace category_id in urls by pk .. but no effect

Comment: Also can you change link in your template to this: `{% url 'add_content' category.id %}`